# Better way to passing parameters conditionally?

Tags: javascript

I need to call a function with a cascade of parameters, but I want to dynamically get rid of some properties.

This is working, but very redundant to write, and painful while there're many conditions:

```js
const skip4 = false;

if(skip4) {
  foo(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, undefined, 9);
} else {
  foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, undefined, 9);
}
```

I tried this and this also puts `undefined` in the argument list which is not what I want.

```js
foo(1, 2, 3, (skip4 ? undefined : 4), 5, 6, (skip7 ? undefined : 7), undefined, 9);
```

This could work but it also filtered out some of the value that intentionally be `undefined`:

```js
foo(...[1, 2, 3, (skip4 ? undefined : 4), 5, 6, (skip7 ? undefined : 7), undefined, 9].filter(i => i));
```

These are the results I expected:

```js
foo(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, undefined, 9);

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, undefined, 9);

foo(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, undefined, 9);

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, undefined, 9);
```

Is there a better way to write this with cleaner syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the array `.filter` method.

```
const skip4 = false;

const args = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, undefined, 9];
foo(...args.filter(v => !(v == 4 && skip4)))
```

which would call `foo(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, undefined, 9)`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a Symbol for the one to skip:

```
 const skip = Symbol(),
     call = (fn, ...args) => fn(...args.filter(it => it !== skip));

 call(foo, 1, 2, 3, skip4 ? skip : 4, 5, 6, 7, undefined);
```

Comment: This works pretty well, thanks! Kinda hope there is an expression or one-line solution for this situation though :)

Comment: No, cause you usually don't need this.